# Dojo on does not catch TitlePane toggle event

Tags: dojo

Dojo.connect is deprecated, but why does the following work for catching a TitlePane toggle event:

```
dojo.connect(myTitlePane, "toggle", function() { alert("toggled"); });
```

while this does not work:

```
on(myTitlePane, "toggle", function() { alert("toggled"); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new Dojo, events are handled with [dojo/on](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html) and normal method calls are handled with [dojo/aspect](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html).

```
aspect.after(p, "toggle", function() {
    alert("toggled.");
});
```

[Handy-dandy jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inanutshellus/mLtvv4cw/).

Comment: Thanks.  I actually tried that but I had a typo in the event name so I thought it wasn't correct.  doh :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `myTitlePane` should be referenced by as :

```
 require(["dojo/aspect"],function(aspect){
     var myTitlePane = registry.byId("myTitlePane");
     aspect.after(myTitlePane, "toggle", function() {
          alert("toggled.");
   }
```

});

Then the `myTitlePane` is dijit object, not `dom` object.
    Then